# How to make the current child page refresh from the master page of an MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I'm developing an MVC application that is essentially a "dashboard" on the home page and the rest of the application is various reports. One of the requirements is to be able to change parameters in the header that affect whatever page you are on. For example, if you are on the home page and looking at data for Group A, you can change to Group B and see the dashboard change. Similar behavior if you are on a report page - change to Group C, and the report refreshes with the appropriate data.

The listing of groups is a dynamically created menu in the master page, so each group option is a link. Normally I'd make each link an ActionLink and direct it to a specific page, but in this case I need the link to write the selection to a database and tell whatever the child page is to refresh.

What's the correct/most efficient/best way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider doing this with a tabbed interface using [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).  In this case each tab corresponds to the action that generates the dashboard for a group.  Switching between tabs causes the action for the tab to reload via AJAX the tab's contents.  You can use the [Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugin to make the tab sticky between sessions -- see the docs for the tabs plugin.